# SQL query from 2 tables for matching condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing an issue to find the correct SQL query. I have a rest api call

`/order?[customerID=][year=][address=][item=][country=]`

and I have to do a sql query to return the order(orderID, order desc) based on the values in the URL. In the DB I have 2 tables

Table1

```
customerName
customerID
year
orderID
orderDesc
country
```

Table2

```
customerName
customerID
year
address
item
quantity
orderID
```

I need to get the orderID and orderDesc from Table1 which satisfies the condition that customerID, year, country equals the values as URL in Table1 and also customerID, year, address,item in Table2(keep in mind thar the orderID should be same). Is this possible. I am new to SQL and struggling to find the solution. Any help would be highly appreciated

Adrin

Comment: Your two tables do not appear to be normalized.  You might want to read up on normalization before you proceed any further.

Comment: Yea true. But unfortunately, the current db is something which I cant actually modify :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple:

```
select t1.orderID, t1.orderDesc
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.orderID=t2.orderID and t1.customerID=t2.customerID and t1.year=t2.year
Where t2.address=@address and t1.year=@year and t1.customerID=@customerID and t2.item=@item and t1.country=@country
```

You must declare the vars or create a stored procedure.

In order to do that, `customerID` needs to be the same in both tables, the condition is in the "ON" after the inner join.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried this option, It seems like 'on t1.orderID=t2.orderID' didn't work. because the result was showing the orderDesc and orderId of all other combinations. ie I have in the result different orderID's. But I believe all other combinations worked out

Comment: You can try with select t1.orderID, t1.orderDesc, t2.orderID for view that both "orderID" are equal.

Comment: You were right.. Both the table have the same ID. It seems like the conditions satisfies fore more cases with different ID. Thanks anyway. You saved my day and I mark this as the correct ans. If you think its good give a thumps up to my question too ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Tim suggested, I recommend normalization before proceeding, but if you must continue, one possible solution would be to use a join.

```
    SELECT t1.OrderID, t1.ORderDesc
    FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 
ON t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID
WHERE t1.CustomerID = @CustomerID
AND t2.CustomerID = @CustomerID
AND t1.Year = @Year
AND t2.Year = @Year
AND t1.Country = @Country
AND t2.Address = @Address
AND t2.Item = @Item
```

Where @Item, @Year, @Country, and @CustomerID are parameters for the values parsed from the URL.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Yea. Thank you Jean. As @Jonathan answered first am marking his as accepted. but your ans is also right and well presented. thumps up for that. thank you for your time

Comment: Haha missed it by a second

Answer (score 1):

You can JOIN both tables and use a WHERE clause to filter the results based on the parameters received by the API.

However please not that this is quite ugly... there seem to be many redundant information between the two tables and as commented by @TimBiegeleisen you would better normalize your data structures before ; that would make the logic of such query much cleaner.

```
select
    a.customerID,
    a.orderDesc
from table1 a
join table2 b 
    on b.orderID = a.orderID
    and b.customerName = a.customerName
    and b.year = a.year
    and b.customerID = a.customerID
where
    a.customerID = :CUSTOMERID 
    and a.year = :YEAR
    and b.address = :ADDRESS
    and b.item = :ITEM
    and a.country = :COUNTRY
```

Comment: Yea. Thankyou. As @Jonathan answered first am marking his as accepted. but your ans is also right and well presented.thumps up for that thank you for your time